# Don't place new-row text under the check mark

Tags: html, css

How could I make this text next to checkmark to have a left margin, if it breaks into the new row? So, any longer sentence should break exactly under the first letter of that sentence... So - the space under the checkmark should stay empty when there's a larger sentence. Here's a pen to demonstrate:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oyGBrX

```
.text {
    margin-left: 35px;
}
.text:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: '\f00c';
    font-size: 20px;
    color: red;
    position: relative;
    top: 2px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use absolute position on the marker so it doesn't effect the text

**See code snippet**

```css
.text {
  padding-left: 35px;
  padding-top:5px;
  position: relative
}

.text:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: '\f00c';
  font-size: 20px;
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="text-container">
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
    <p class="text">Small amount of text</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="text-container">
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
    <p class="text">Large amount of text and more text lorem This should start under the "Large", and have a left margin, so the space under the checkmark is empty</p>
  </div>
</div>
```